# How to plot multiple traces with trendlines?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, regression, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot trendlines on multiple traces on scatters in plotly. I'm kind of stumped on how to do it.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_df['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=df_df['Height (meters)'], 
                         name='Douglas Fir', mode='markers')
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wp['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=df_wp['Height (meters)'],  
                         name='White Pine',mode='markers'),
             )
fig.update_layout(title="Tree Circumference vs Height (meters)",
                  xaxis_title=df_df['Circumference (meters)'].name,
                  yaxis_title=df_df['Height (meters)'].name,
                  title_x=0.5)

fig.show()
```

Trying to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've already put together a procedure that solves your problem, but I would like to mention that you can use [`plotly.express`](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) and do the very same thing with only a very few lines of code. Using [`px.scatter()`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter) there are actually two *slightly* different ways, depending on whether your data is of a [long or wide format](https://towardsdatascience.com/reshape-pandas-dataframe-with-pivot-table-in-python-tutorial-and-visualization-2248c2012a31). Your data seems to be of the latter format, since you're asking:

> how can I make this work with separate traces?

So I'll start with that. And I'll use a subset of the built-in dataset `px.data.stocks()` since you haven't provided a data sample.

#### Code 1 - Wide data

```
fig_wide = px.scatter(df_wide, x = 'index', y = ['AAPL', 'MSFT'],
                      trendline = 'ols',
                     )
```

#### Code 2 - Long data

```
fig_long = px.scatter(df_long, x= 'index', y = 'value',
                      color = 'variable',
                      trendline = 'ols')
```

#### Plot 1 - Identical results

[image]

#### About the data:

A dataframe of a wide format typically has an index with unique values in the left-most column, variable names in the column headers, and corresponding values for each variable per index in the columns like this:

```
index AAPL      MSFT
0     1.000000  1.000000
1     1.011943  1.015988
2     1.019771  1.020524
3     0.980057  1.066561
4     0.917143  1.040708
```

Here, adding information about another variable would require adding another column.

A dataframe of a long format, on the other hand, typically organizes the same data with only (though not *necessarily* only) three columns;  `index, variable and value`:

```
index  variable  value
0      AAPL      1.000000
1      AAPL      1.011943
.
.
100    MSFT      1.720717
101    MSFT      1.752239
```

An contrary to the wide format, this means that `index` will have duplicate values. But for a good reason.

#### So what's the difference?

If you look at `Code 1` you'll see that the only thing you need to specify for `px.scatter` in order to get multiple traces with trendlines, in this case `AAPL and MSFT on the y-axis versus an index on the x-axis`, is  `trendline = 'ols'`. This is because `plotly.express` [automatically identifies the data format](https://medium.com/plotly/beyond-tidy-plotly-express-now-accepts-wide-form-and-mixed-form-data-bdc3e054f891) as wide and knows how to apply the trendlines correctly. Different columns means different catrgories for which a trace and trendline are produced.

As for the "long approach", you've got both `GOOG and AAPL` in the same `variable` column, and values for both of them in the `value` column. But setting `color = 'variable'` lets plotly.express know how to categorize the `variable` column, correctly separate the data in in the `value` column, and thus correctly produce the trendlines. A different name in the `variable` column means that `index` and `value` in the same row belongs to different categories, for which a new trace and trendline are built.

#### Any pros and cons?

The arguably only advantage with the wide format is that it's easier to read (particularly for those of us damaged by too many years of sub-excellent data handling with Excel). And one great advantage with the long format is that you can easily illustrate more dimensions of the data if you have more categories with, for example, different symbols or sizes for the markers.

Another advantage with the long format occurs if the dataset changes, for example with the addition of another variable `'AMZN'`. Then the name and the values of that variable will occur in the already existing columns instead of adding another one like you would for the wide format. This means that you actually won't have to change the code in:

```
fig_long = px.scatter(df_long, x= 'index', y = 'value',
                      color = 'variable',
                      trendline = 'ols')
```

... in order to add the data to the figure.

While for the wide format, you would have to specify `y = ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'AMZN']` in:

```
fig_wide = px.scatter(df_wide, x = 'index', y = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN'],
                      trendline = 'ols',
                     )
```

And I would strongly argue that this outweighs the slight inconvenience of speifying `color = 'variable'` in:

```
fig_long = px.scatter(df_long, x= 'index', y = 'value',
                      color = 'variable',
                      trendline = 'ols')
```

#### Plot 2 - A new variable:

[image]

#### Complete code

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
# df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df_wide = df.drop(['date', 'GOOG', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'FB'], axis = 1).reset_index()
# df_wide = df.drop(['date', 'GOOG', 'NFLX', 'FB'], axis = 1).reset_index()
df_long = pd.melt(df_wide, id_vars = 'index')
df_long

fig_wide = px.scatter(df_wide, x = 'index', y = ['AAPL', 'MSFT'],
                      trendline = 'ols',
                     )

fig_long = px.scatter(df_long, x= 'index', y = 'value',
                      color = 'variable',
                      trendline = 'ols')

# fig_long.show()
fig_wide.show()
```

Comment: but how can I make this work with separate traces?

Comment: If you got time I'd love it if you could update it. Please!

Comment: @David54321 I'd be happy to. But first, could you just clarify what the *real* challenge is? Is it (1) that you have to use `go.Scatter()` or is it (2) that you've got your data organized in a dataframe with a wide format? If it's the latter, then the solution is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved it. Basically I used numpy polyfit function to calculation my slop. I then added the slop for each data set as a tracer

```
import numpy as np

df_m, df_b = np.polyfit(df_df['Circumference (meters)'].to_numpy(), df_df['Height (meters)'].to_numpy(), 1)
wp_m, wp_b = np.polyfit(df_wp['Circumference (meters)'].to_numpy(), df_wp['Height (meters)'].to_numpy(), 1)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_df['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=df_df['Height (meters)'], 
                         name='Douglas Fir', mode='markers')
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_df['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=(df_m*df_df['Circumference (meters)'] + df_b),
                         name='douglas fir trendline',
                         mode='lines')
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wp['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=df_wp['Height (meters)'],  
                         name='White Pine',mode='markers'),
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wp['Circumference (meters)'], 
                         y=(wp_m * df_wp['Circumference (meters)'] + wp_b),
                         name='white pine trendline',
                         mode='lines')
             )
fig.update_layout(title="Tree Circumference vs Height (meters)",
                  xaxis_title=df_df['Circumference (meters)'].name,
                  yaxis_title=df_df['Height (meters)'].name,
                  title_x=0.5)

fig.show()
```

[image]